# NodeJS does not give error notifications when missing parenthesis

Tags: node.js

Im a rails/php develop and currently learning nodejs, Im just a bit puzzled that they dont give syntax errors or warnings whenever you mistype something.

For example:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
var ar = [];
var nm = '';

rl.question("What is your name? ", function(name){
  nm = name;

  rl.setPrompt(`words? `);
  rl.prompt();
  rl.on('line', function(str){

    ar.push(str.trim());

    if(str.toLowerCase().trim() == 'exit'){
      rl.close();  // <--- I forgot to add '()' on this line but the program still runs, no warnings at all. 
    }else{
      rl.setPrompt(`add more ('exit' to leave)`);
      rl.prompt();
    }

  });
});

// Because I forgot '()' this event did not execute '
rl.on('close', function(){
  console.log(name " " + ar);
  process.exit();
});
```

In other languages, it usually says an error on that line but in nodejs there is none and it took me 5 mins to figure out why the close event is not executing.

Im new to this language, could anybody explain why?

Comment: `In other languages, it usually says an error on that line` well it depends on the editor you're using... if you use Notepad it won't :) In the case of Node, a rich editor like VS Code with JSHint installed _will_ run some checks on your code

Comment: Im using atom.. it doesnt say anything..

Comment: Because atom is a text editor. Check out https://atom.io/packages/atom-jshint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rl.close` is a valid reference to a function.  Per the Javascript language specification, it's not an actual Javascript error of any kind.

It turns out not to do anything if you aren't assigning or passing it to something so some Lint programs will flag it as a warning, but it is not technically a Javascript error.

For example, jsHint (a Lint program for Javascript) will give you this warning:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Because the Javascript language is fairly permissive in what it allows you to write and what it will parse, it is generally recommended that you run your code through a lint program and fix or understand every warning you see there.  This will generally save you a lot of time.

Comment: I see , but isnt that a bad thing? if you have a a few hundred lines of code , it would be very difficult to find whats causing the issue,  Im just the console, is there any program that i can use to give me warnings?

Comment: @XDProgrammer JSHint is one

Comment: @XDProgrammer - I'm not going to argue what is or isn't a bad thing (that's pretty much pure opinion).  The language is the way it is and we can't change it.  If you're going to program in it, then learn to use the appropriate tools to minimize your risks.  I've already included a recommendation to use [jsHint](http://jshint.com/), though there are many similar tools to choose from and some are built into editors too.

Comment: @XDProgrammer - Since it looks like you may be relatively new to stack overflow, if this answered your question, then please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer.  That will also earn you some stack overflow reputation points for following the proper procedure.